# The image cropped by the rectangle drawn within canvas is not the same as the actual cropped image

Tags: reactjs, canvas

```
const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);

const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const startX = useRef(null);
  const startY = useRef(null);
  const canvasOffSetX = useRef(null);
  const canvasOffSetY = useRef(null);

  const contextRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = videoRef.current.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = videoRef.current.clientHeight;

    contextRef.current = canvas.getContext("2d");
    contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#484444";

    contextRef.current.strokeStyle = "black";
    contextRef.current.lineWidth = 2;

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      setIsDrawing(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [isDrawing]);

const cropImage = async (xtl, ytl) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        import.meta.env.VITE_CROP_IMAGE,
        {
          filepath: newFilePath,
          xtl,
          ytl
        },
        {
          proxy: false
        }
      );

      const filePaths = res.data.filepath;
      setCalculatedFilePath(filePaths);

      await calculateSITI(calculatedFilePath);

      return filePaths;
    } catch (error) {
      // console.error("crop Error:", error);

      // throw new Error(error.message);
      toast.fire({ icon: "error", title: "Crop Error", text: error.name });
      if (error.response) console.error("API Response Data:", error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timeoutId;

    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);

      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        func(...args);
      }, delay);
    };
  };

  const startDrawingRectangle = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    startX.current = nativeEvent.pageX - canvasOffSetX.current;
    startY.current = nativeEvent.pageY - canvasOffSetY.current;

    setIsDrawing(true);
  };

  const drawRectangle = async ({ nativeEvent }) => {

    if (!isDrawing) return;

    if (!nativeEvent || !contextRef.current) return;

    const rect = videoRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const context = contextRef.current;

    if (context) {
      const newMouseX = nativeEvent.pageX - canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const newMouseY = nativeEvent.pageY - canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const rectWidth = Math.min(512, Math.abs(newMouseX - startX.current));
      const rectHeight = Math.min(512, Math.abs(newMouseY - startY.current));
      const xtl = Math.min(startX.current, newMouseX);
      const ytl = Math.min(startY.current, newMouseY);

      contextRef.current.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
      contextRef.current.strokeRect(xtl + rect.left, ytl + rect.top, rectWidth, rectHeight);
      contextRef.current.globalAlpha = 0.4;
      contextRef.current.fillRect(xtl + rect.left, ytl + rect.top, rectWidth, rectHeight);
      contextRef.current.globalAlpha = 1;

      startX.current = xtl;
      startY.current = ytl;
      await cropImage(xtl, ytl);
    }
  };

  const debouncedDrawRectangle = debounce(drawRectangle, 100);

  const stopDrawingRectangle = () => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

return (
     <div
                style={{
                  position: "relative",
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  overflow: "hidden"
                }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    inset: 0,
                    visibility: checkVisibility
                  }}
                  onWheel={onTimelineWheel}
                >
                  {!isFileOpened && (
                    <NoFileLoaded
                      mifiLink={mifiLink}
                      currentCutSeg={currentCutSeg}
                      onClick={openFilesDialog}
                      darkMode={darkMode}
                    />
                  )}

                  <video
                    muted={playbackVolume === 0}
                    ref={videoRef}
                    style={{
                      width: "100%",
                      height: "100%"
                    }}
                    src={fileUri}
                    onPlay={onStartPlaying}
                    onPause={onStopPlaying}
                    onDurationChange={onDurationChange}
                    onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
                    onError={onVideoError}
                  >
                    <source src="output.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <canvas
                    ref={canvasRef}
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      inset: 0,
                      pointerEvents: "auto",
                      width: "100%",
                      height: "100%"
                    }}
                    onMouseMove={debouncedDrawRectangle}
                    onMouseDown={startDrawingRectangle}
                    onMouseLeave={stopDrawingRectangle}
                  ></canvas>
              </div>
             </div>
)
```

As you can see in the attached photo, the image cropped by the rectangle I drew within the canvas is different from the actual cropped image, and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried applying the pageX,pageY / clientX,clientY / screenX,screenY etc that exist in the nativeEvent property within the startDrawingRectangle, drawRectangle functions, but still the image that exists within the drawn rectangle and the image cropped by that rectangle are different. I would like to know how to solve this.

Also, the Y value of the mouse pointer and the actual starting point of the rectangle seem to be different.

[image]

[image]